# React Filter and Map data for Datagrid returning no values

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter, datagrid

I suspect it is a syntax issue.  When I use the same approach for  instead of  I do get the expected results.  The data is coming from an endpoint through the import of getAssembly which is generated via await fetch and the results are being rendered as JSON before the data is imported.

The commented out code on line how I assume the commanded need to be executed and I get no error, but no data is rendered.  The code on line 50 works fine but does not provide the filtering.   I intend the use the value in the typeName variable once the filtering is working.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { getAssembly } from "./GetAssembly";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 300 },
  { field: "status", headerName: "Status", width: 90 },
  { field: "atype", headerName: "AType", width: 80 },
  { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 350 },
  { field: "time", headerName: "Start Time", width: 150 },
  { field: "org", headerName: "Organization", width: 350 },
];

export default function SelectAssembly() {

  const [typeName, setTypeName] = useState([""]);
  // const [assemRows, setAssemRows] = useState([]);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    assembly: [],
    assembtypename: [],
    unsignenList: [],
  });

  const handleTypeChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setTypeName(value);
  };

  console.log(typeName);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    getAssembly().then((res) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, assembly: res.assemblies }));
    });
  }, []);

  const typeSelection = [
    ...new Set(state.assembly.map((item) => item.assemblyType)),
  ];

 //const assemList = state.assembly.filter(assem => assem === "batch").map(assem => {
   const assemList = state.assembly.map((assem) => {
    return {
      id: assem.assemblyId,
      status: assem.status,
      atype: assem.assemblyType,
      name: assem.name,
      time: assem.timeStarted,
      org: assem.organizationId,
      asid: assem.referenceId,
      pmap: assem.propertiesMap,
    };
  });

  // const unsignedList = assemList.filter((str) => {
  //   //str can include or str can equal with === (return str.includes("import");)
  //   return str === "import";
  // });

  return (
    <div>
      <InputLabel sx={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Assembly Type</InputLabel>
      <Select
        label="Type"
        value={typeName}
        sx={{ height: 35, fontSize: 10 }}
        fullWidth
        focused
        onChange={handleTypeChange}
      >
        {typeSelection.map((types) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={types.indexOf(types) > -1} value={types}>
              <ListItemText primary={types} />
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <DataGrid
        density="compact"
        hideFooterRowCount
        rows={assemList}
        // rows={unsignedList}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={15}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[15]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the posting got jacked up.  it should read I use the same approach for an unsigned list instead of a datagrid

Comment: I have created a Code Sandbox for your code => https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-frost-nhlb6?file=/src/App.js. Can add initial state data (sample data from the request) for `assembly`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jim Ptak at Southwire for helping me see the problem.  In the filter method I did not specify the particular element to filter on.  Once the code was modified as follows:

```js
const assemList = state.assembly.filter(assem => assem.assemblyType === "MO import").map(assem => {
   //const assemList = state.assembly.map((assem) => {
    return {
      id: assem.assemblyId,
      status: assem.status,
      atype: assem.assemblyType,
      name: assem.name,
      time: assem.timeStarted,
      org: assem.organizationId,
      asid: assem.referenceId,
      pmap: assem.propertiesMap,
    };
  });
```

the contents of the datagrid filters perfectly.